# Is there a way to flatten a json file values into a list without knowing it's structure ahead?

Tags: python, json, algorithm, data-structures

I am building an API based website and I am trying to design a generic function that will get a json file and will parse all its values into a list without knowing the json structure ahead
(each object can contain either dict, list or a tuple which in they're turn can also contain dict's list's and tuple's)

I've looked for solutions for days now and I didn't find anything yet.

I tried it in two ways, I'll add both of the functions for your review and an example of a json file I want to parse.

Method 1: this method returns result which contains dict's with other types

```
def format_data(self,args):
    result =[]
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(args[arg], dict):
            self.format_data(args[arg])
            # for val in self.format_data(args[arg]):
            #     result.append(val)
        if isinstance(args[arg], tuple) or isinstance(args[arg], list):
            for val in args[arg]:
                result.append(val)
        else:
            result.append(args[arg])
    return result
```

Method 2: with this method I've tried building a recursive function that will only append objects once they only conation str's and they're str's values , otherwise; keep on calling
This method does not return the full list of values.

```
        def format_data(self,args):
    result =[]
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, dict):
            self.format_data(arg)
        elif isinstance(args[arg],dict):
            self.format_data(args[arg])
        elif isinstance(args[arg], list) or isinstance(args[arg], tuple):
            for val in args[arg]:
                if isinstance(args[arg], str):
                    result.append(val) #copy only vlues with str type in the object
            if self.check_if_only_string(args[arg]): #locate all values dif then str that contain's str and copy them
                for val in args[arg]:
                    result.append(val)
            else:
                self.format_data(args[arg]) #args[arg] must be str

        result.append(args[arg])
    return result

def check_if_only_string(self, data):
    '''retuens flase if data obj has any kind of objects other then str'''
    for key in data:
        if isinstance(key, dict):
            return False
        elif not isinstance(key, str):
            return False
    return True
```

An ex. for input and outout:
Input:

```
{
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "serverTime": 1637752583921,
    "rateLimits": [
        {
            "rateLimitType": "REQUEST_WEIGHT",
            "interval": "MINUTE",
            "intervalNum": 1,
            "limit": 1200
        },
        {
            "rateLimitType": "ORDERS",
            "interval": "SECOND",
            "intervalNum": 10,
            "limit": 50
        },
        {
            "rateLimitType": "ORDERS",
            "interval": "DAY",
            "intervalNum": 1,
            "limit": 160000
        },
        {
            "rateLimitType": "RAW_REQUESTS",
            "interval": "MINUTE",
            "intervalNum": 5,
            "limit": 6100
        }
    ],
    "exchangeFilters": [],
}
```

Output:

```
[UTC,1637752583921,REQUEST_WEIGHT,MINUTE,1,1200,ORDERS]
```

and so on to all the values

Comment: What's your **specific** question?

Comment: Is there a way to parse a json file values into a list without knowing it's structure ahead?

Comment: Please provide an example of input and output. How are you planning to flatten out something with 3-4 hierarchy into a list?

Comment: What has this to do with JSON parsing? It looks like you are just attempting to flatten the data structure.

Comment: I guess that would be a more accurate description. Thank you for your help and input

Comment: So this has nothing to do with JSON parsing. You just want to flatten the structure.

Comment: So, you have a tree, and you want to produce the list of leaves of that tree?

Comment: Hi gre_gor, Yes, I might have miss-spoked with my phrase.. This was fixed, thank you!
Yes Stef, thats a great way to think about it, thank you for that perspective and your ansewr!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if you're simply looking for a depth-first search through a tree, to produce a list of leaves of the tree.

```py
def leaves(t):
    if isinstance(t, dict):
        for v in t.values():
            yield from leaves(v)
    elif isinstance(t, list):
        for v in t:
            yield from leaves(v)
    else:
        yield t

print( list(leaves(json.loads(example))) )
# ['UTC', 1637752583921, 'REQUEST_WEIGHT', 'MINUTE', 1, 1200, 'ORDERS', 'SECOND', 10, 50, 'ORDERS', 'DAY', 1, 160000, 'RAW_REQUESTS', 'MINUTE', 5, 6100]
```